# Should I use PHP 'SORT_FLAG_CASE' with bitwise AND or bitwise OR to sort an array case insensitively using sort() function?

Tags: php

Suppose you've been given an array like,

```
$books  = array('Book21','BOOK22','book20');.
```

Which is the right operator(bitwise AND or betwise OR) to use with `SORT_FLAG_CASE` and `SORT_STRING` flags to sort this array case insensitively? Because in http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php, only bitwise OR operator seems to be mentioned.

I currently use PHP version 7.2.

Thank you.

Comment: As the page you linked suggests, you should use bitwise OR.

Answer (score 0):

You want the bitwise or operator `|` or just the addition operator `+`.

```
SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_STRING
```

If you dump these values, you'll note they're valued as such:

```
SORT_FLAG_CASE int(8)
SORT_STRING    int(2)
```

Or, in binary:

```
SORT_FLAG_CASE 00001000
SORT_STRING    00000010
```

I.e., flags like this are generally integers with only a single bit set. Thus, by bitwise or'ing them, you get all the combined flags turned on:

```
00001000 SORT_FLAG_CASE
00000010 SORT_STRING    
00001010 SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_FLAG_CASE
```

If you use bitwise and, you'll get none of them.

```
00001000 SORT_FLAG_CASE
00000010 SORT_STRING    
00000000 SORT_FLAG_CASE & SORT_FLAG_CASE
```